# Bootstrap DatePicker glyphicon not aligning or calling calendar?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using Eternicode's Bootstrap-Datepicker and I would like to get the glyphicon to align just to the right of the input field. Currently the input is aligned to the left and the glyphicon is aligned to the far right with a bunch of space between them. I would also like to make it so that the calendar will show if the user clicks on the glyphicon. Currently it's only showing the calendar by clicking on the input field.

I've done some research and from what I've found it says to wrap the input-group with a class set to the width. In my case it's col-md-10 to match up with the other input fields. If I set it to col-md-3 then it does align the glyphicon up against the input field but then that combination is too short to match the others fields. If I set it to col-md-4 it puts a space between the input and glyphicon. Do I have any other choice but to set it to col-md-3 as well as set all the other columns to that size?

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CallDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input id="callDatepicker" class="datepicker form-control" name="CallDate" type="text" />
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CallDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, is there a way to add the pop-up calendar to the glyphicon as well? I tried adding the datepicker class to the addon group but that didn't seem to work. I don't see any errors in the F12 tools either.

I tried this without success.

```
<div class="input-group date">
    <input id="callDatepicker" class="datepicker form-control" name="CallDate" type="text" />
    <div class="input-group-addon datepicker">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```